# Spotify API: Get an Artist based on the name not the artist's ID

Tags: web-applications, get, spotify

The endpoint states that you have to use its Spotify ID to get its info. Is there a way to achieve this using the name of the artist instead of the ID?

```
GET https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/{artist-name}
```

Answer (score 2):

As you can imagine, there are many artists with the same or similar names! You should use the [Search endpoint](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/search-item/) to search for the artist. This will return an artist object with the ID, which you can use in future calls.